# How to pass dynamic file location in Form API?

Tags: 7, forms, files

my requirement is to upload files to specific folders. How can I achieve this by using form api. How can I modify below code such that upload_location should be dynamic. Uploaded file should save into the Folder name provided by the user. 
I tried below code but not worked.

**#submit element is not calling custom_document_submit function.**

```
 $form['folder_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Folder Name'),
  );
  $form['document'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('xml')),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#submit' => array('custom_document_submit'),
    );
function custom_document_submit($form, &$form_state){
  $destination = $form_state['values']['folder_name'];
  $validators = array();
  $file = file_save_upload('document', $validators, 'public://'.$destination);
}
```

Comment: `managed_file` does not support `#submit`

Comment: Ohh thank you. May I know how can I achieve that. #upload_location should be dynamic one.

Comment: How about using Form Ajax to rebuild the form with the updated `#upload_location` on `managed_file`?

Comment: If its succeed that will be great.. May I know how can I use form ajax in my case?

Comment: I will answer you, wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using ajax to update the `#upload_location` on demand.

However, ajax on `managed_file` element is quite tricky. Because `managed_file` has its own ajax handling for uploading file. It only rebuilds the file element itself and returns lack of data from other fields during during file upload ajax. So it need to be fixed in some ***hacky*** way

Example code:

```php
function mymodule_custom_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $input = &$form_state['input'];
  $values = &$form_state['values'];

  $form['folder_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Folder Name'),
    '#submit' => array('mymodule_custom_form_folder_name_submit'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_custom_form_folder_name_ajax',
      'wrapper' => 'edit-file-ajax-wrapper',
      'event' => 'keyup',
    ),
  );

  // HACK: manually construct the folder_name value.
  // $form_state['values'] is empty for other field in file upload ajax
  // because it only rebuild the element rather then the whole form.
  if (!isset($values['folder_name']) && !empty($input['folder_name'])) {
    $values['folder_name'] = form_type_textfield_value($form['folder_name'], $input['folder_name']);
  }

  $form['file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'File',
    '#disabled' => empty($values['folder_name']) && empty($input['folder_name']),
    '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg')),
    '#upload_location' => !empty($values['folder_name']) ? 'public://' . $values['folder_name'] : 'public://',
  );

function mymodule_custom_form_folder_name_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  unset($form['file']['#disabled']);
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function mymodule_custom_form_folder_name_ajax(&$form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['file'];
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting disabled file upload on the page. One more thing is I am doing this thing on admin page. So form function I cant use I guess. I have written ur  form elements inside mymodule_admin() function.

Comment: @Suraj Yes, I make it disabled by default. You can remove the `#disabled` code if you don't want this feature. And, if you are using form API to construct form in admin page. It should work.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I am bit new to this thing. How can i use form api in admin page. I know only hting is to display in admin page we have to use mymodule_admin function. Whatever i will write inside this function that will display on admin page. So where can i use form api here.

Comment: @Suraj You can read [Creating a module configuration (settings) page](https://www.drupal.org/node/206761) first.